# Passing Url to ColumnFixture

Tags: c#, fitnesse

I'm working on Fitnesse Test Project with C# and Slim.
I'm trying to pass Url address as a parameter to the ColumnFixture. 
Url address should be the same for all test cases so I decided to use !define keyword to define my url. In Fitnesse test I have:

```
!define webServiceUrl {http://mytestserver.address.svc}

|!-MyNamespace.SearchClientFixture-!                       |
|webServiceUrl   |contactPhoneNumber|contactId?|identificationResult?|
|${webServiceUrl}|922222222         |0         |notfound             |
|${webServiceUrl}|                  |0         |notfound             |
```

${webServiceUrl} is rendered as HTML anchor tag and the value passed to my ColumnFixture class is also HTML anchor markup

`<a href="http://mytestserver.address.svc">http://mytestserver.address.svc</a>`

I tried to escape HTML with `!<text>! and !-` fitnesse tags but it doesn't work.
My questions are:
1. How to escape HTML in my case?
2. How to pass single value to ColumnFixture shared among all test cases? Is it possible to send value to the SetUp method?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the ! before the first line in the table.  That is supposed to turn off wiki rendering for the whole table.

```
!|MyNamespace.SearchClientFixture                       |
|webServiceUrl   |contactPhoneNumber|contactId?|identificationResult?|
|${webServiceUrl}|922222222         |0         |notfound             |
|${webServiceUrl}|                  |0         |notfound             |
```

This has worked for me and all of my projects.  Only trouble is when you want actual wiki markup in the table (such as !today).